# Assigning empty array to a pointer at compile time in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, structure

I have a structure in C which is intended to store information about character lcd's. It looks like this:

```
typedef struct CharLCD {
    uint8_t rows, columns, currentLine;
    uint8_t* lineAddress;
    uint8_t* pContent;
} CharLCD;
```

I would like to create an instance of that structure and populate `pContent` with pointer to empty array of known size. I solved this problem for the `lineAddress` by listing all the values but I expect the `pContent` to store 64 values which makes that approach unpractical. I can assign the values programmatically later but I need to create the array:

```
CharLCD lcd16x4 ={
    .rows = 4,
    .columns = 16,
    .currentLine = 0,
    .lineAddress = {0x00, 0x40, 0x10, 0x50},
    .pContent = /*uninitialized array of size 64*/
};
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this than creating an empty array as a new variable and then storing the pointer to `pContent`? The code is intended to run on an embedded platform which doesn't allow dynamic allocation of memory.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: In the first code snippet, you are referring to a member variable named `lineAddresses`, but in the second one, you are referring to `lineAddress`. Please ensure that the names that you use are consistent.

Comment: `lineAddress = {0x00, 0x40, 0x10, 0x50}`?  If you plan on using dynamic allocation using `malloc()` etc. for `lineAddress` and other fields, and if those values change, how do you plan on tracking whether or not you need to call `free()` or similar on those fields in order to either avoid memory leaks or trying to free static values?

Comment: The line `.lineAddress = {0x00, 0x40, 0x10, 0x50}` [is not valid in plain ISO C](https://godbolt.org/z/nrqKqYvG7), even if you fix the mismatch that I mentioned in my first comment. Did you intend to use a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) instead? Or are you using a platform which actually accepts this line as valid code?

Comment: I corrected the error (lineAddress/lineAddresses). I am using pic32 with xc32 compiler which is compiles `.lineAddress = {0x00, 0x40, 0x10, 0x50}` without errors. I am not going to be using dynamic allocation. There is actually no need for it in my code since the sizes of the variables are not going to change. I just wanted to create a structure which can be simply modified to accomodate different sizes of displays - 20x2, 16x2, 16x4 etc.

Comment: There is no such thing as "empty array of size 64". Perhaps you mean an array full of zeros.

Comment: The wording is maybe unfortunate I meant array of size 64 without it's values being defined. I basically need just the space in memory and don't care what is stored there - I will assign the values later in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal).

```
CharLCD lcd16x4 ={
    .rows = 4,
    .columns = 16,
    .currentLine = 0,
    .lineAddress = {0x00, 0x40, 0x10, 0x50},
    .pContent = (uint8_t[64]){0}
};
```

You could also just declare the 64-element array and refer to that in the initialization of the structure.

```
uint8_t lcd16_content[64];
CharLCD lcd16x4 ={
    .rows = 4,
    .columns = 16,
    .currentLine = 0,
    .lineAddress = {0x00, 0x40, 0x10, 0x50},
    .pContent = lcd16_content
};
```

The only effective difference between these is that the array has a name independent of the structure member.

Comment: You'd [need to be careful with compound literals](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5p5): "If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the object has static storage duration; **otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with the enclosing block**."

Comment: Thank you, compound literal was what I was looking for. I knew about the other solution but it seemed rather cumbersome. Especially if I needed to create more instances.